# Clock settings are disabled from Time & Date Settings

Tags: indicator, clock

In my time & Date settings clock settings seems to be disable. Which default package is missing on my system ?

[image: Screen short of settings]

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Also try `sudo gnome-control-center`

Comment: You should never have to run gnome-control-center as root.  Thus - `gksudo gnome-control-center` is NOT an answer.  You have other issues that need to be resolved.  Try creating another user account.  Do you have the same problem?

Answer (score 37):

I realize that this is an old issue, but given that I experienced the same problem, and that this question comes up high in Google, I figured I'd put a response in.

In Ubuntu 13.10, I had the same issue, and I solved it by entering the following command in the terminal:

`killall unity-panel-service`

This immediately reset the panel, and displayed the clock.

Obviously, I was running Unity when I experienced this issue.

I found this answer at [Upgraded to 13.10 now clock settings are all disabled and clock does not display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360690/upgraded-to-13-10-now-clock-settings-are-all-disabled-and-clock-does-not-display)

Comment: I just had this exact problem, and this solution fixed it. I vote for removing the off-topic label, if possible.